# trying to connect to an openVMS server

Tags: unix, virtual-machine, openvms

I am running a Unix based virtual machine and I am trying to write a script that will connect to a specific openVMS server.

I don't know why ,but this became more difficult as I discovered that:

1) I don't have the 'expect' command.

2) When I use rlogin -l option , and then I enter my username , the server still asks for username and only then he asks for the password (even though it is *supposed* to only ask for my password).

3) when I tried to write to a temp file the username and password and then use the following command : "rlogin server

Can you please give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a communication proxy for the UNIX user on the VMS server.

```
TCPIP> ADD PROXY vmsuser /HOST=host /REMOTE_USER=unixuser
```

For each host, be sure to define the host name and any aliases. Or add the host as an IP address.

Also see   http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/83final/6526/6526pro_041.html#bottom_041